# Preciso de ajuda em analisar uma lista e printar quais elementos mais se repetem igualmente na lista. PYTHON

Tags: python

serv = [0,1,1,0,9,7]

Os itens da lista que mais se repetem são o 0 e 1, porém não consegui pensar em nada que eu possa fazer pra chegar isso.

Tentei fixar o 1º elemento ,comparar com os outros e armazenar isso em uma outra lista som e cheguei nisso:

som = [2,2,2,2,1,1] e definitivamente n sei como prosseguir com isso para chegar em final = [0,1].

```
 def mais_requisitados(serv):

    final = []
    som = []
    for i in range(0,len(serv),1):
       b = 0
       som.append(b)
    
    for i in serv:
       for j in range(0,len(serv),1):
         if serv[j] == i:
             som[j] += 1

    return print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um dicionário para armazenar as quantidades de cada elemento:

```py
def mais_requisitados(serv):
    dict_count = {}

    for elem in serv:
        # incrementa se a chave já existir
        # marca como 1 se for a primeira vez
        if elem in dict_count:
            dict_count[elem] += 1
        else:
            dict_count[elem] = 1
    # pega o maior valor do contador
    max_elem = max(dict_count.values())
    # cria lista com as chaves que possuem maior valor
    final = [key for key, value in dict_count.items() if value == max_elem]
    return final # [0, 1]
```

Comment: Será que tem alguma outra forma mais trivial de se fazer ? Ainda não cheguei a ver dicionário, mas se não tiver outra forma vou dar uma estuda em dicionário

Comment: @Moreira Você pode também usar uma lista onde o índice representa o número e o valor, a quantidade de vezes que ele aparece, mas esse método gera listas muito grandes. Na sua lista `serv` dada como exemplo ficaria `[2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`. Assim basta pegar os índices do maior elemento.